# Connecting formal Laurent series to complex analysis?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, definition

From what I have read and this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379185/for-bbbkx-what-and-where-is-x-in-sum-n-0-infty-a-nxn), the formal Laurent series $\in \Bbb{K}(\!(x)\!)$ can be thought of as (semi-)infinite sequences written in the form:
$$\sum^\infty_{n=d|d\ne-\infty}a_nx^n\quad \text{where}\quad a_n \in\Bbb{K}$$

with the following designation of notation:
\[\begin{aligned}(a,0,0,0...)\quad& \text{denoted by}& a=ax^0\\
(0,a,0,0...)\quad& \text{denoted by}& ax=ax^1\\ 
(0,0,a,0...)\quad &\text{denoted by}& ax^2 \end{aligned}\]
<sub>I will denote this type of Laurent series FLS (formal Laurent series).</sub>

---

---

In complex analysis however the Laurent series of a function $f(z)$ is given by:
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k(z-a)^k$$
where:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{k+1}}dz$$
This is defined on an annulus about $a$ in which $f(z)$ is analytic.

<sub>I will denote this type of Laurent series CLS (complex Laurent series).</sub>

---

---

As we can see there are some difference between these the FLS and CLS:

1. The FLS lives in the space of (semi-)infinite sequences whilst the CLS lives in the space of functions $f:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$.
2. The FLS is not permitted to have an infinite lower bound whilst the CLS does.
3. For CLS we can come we can come up with a property of convergence whilst for the FLS we can't.

---

---

**My Question**: How are the FLS and CLS linked, in such away that reconciles there differences? i.e. what is the connection between them.

---

---

<sub>If you could provide references, if you used them, that would be great.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Those are the kind of things you should investigate :

- $\displaystyle\mathbb{C}[z] = \{ \sum_{n=0}^d a_n z^n, a_n \in \mathbb{C}, d \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\displaystyle\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}] = \{ \sum_{n=-d}^d a_n z^n, a_n \in \mathbb{C}, d \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are the sets of complex polynomials in $z,z^{-1}$. They are $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces, $\mathbb{C}$-algebras and  integral domains.
- In the same way that $\mathbb{R}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ for its (Archimedean) absolute value, the ring $A_{(r,R)}$ of complex Laurent series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n$ converging uniformly for $r < |z| < R$ is the completion of the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}]$ for the norm $$\|\sum_{n=-d}^d a_n z_n\| = \sup_{z \in \mathbb{C},|z| \in (r,R)} |\sum_{n=-d}^d a_n z_n|$$
  Also the multiplication is continuous for [this norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra) : $\|fg\| \le \|f\| \,\|g\|$, thus the multiplication stays defined in $A_{(r,R)}$ which is an integral domain and a Banach algebra.
- The ring of formal power series $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is the closure of $\mathbb{C}[z]$ for the (non-Archimedean) [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) $|\sum_{n=d}^D a_n z^n| = 2^{-d}$ if $a_d \ne 0$, while the ring of formal Laurent series $\mathbb{C}((z)) = \mathbb{C}[z^{-1}] \, [[z]] = \{\sum_{-d}^\infty a_n z^n \}$ is the closure of $\mathbb{C}[z,z^{-1}]$ (and it is also isomorphic to the closure of $\mathbb{C}(z) = \text{Frac } \mathbb{C}[z]$).

  Since $|fg| = |f|\, |g|$, the multiplication and the absolute value stays defined in $\mathbb{C}[[z]],\mathbb{C}((z))$.